# Django / File not found when adding a new app

Tags: django

I have 2 apps. I have added a third one called Verge3D

Main urls.py

```
path('verge3D/',include('verge3D.urls')),
```

In my urls.py / Verge3D app :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home3D',views.myFirst3D,name="home3D"),
]
```

In my views.py / Verge 3D app

```
def myFirst3D(request):
    return render(request,'3Dfiles/earth.html')
```

The problem is :

Django searches this 3Dfiles/earth.html still in my first app location (it works when I create this directory/files in my fist app Templates directory)

Strangely I don't have this problem with app n°2

Comment: Did you add the 3rd app to the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes and for the templates variable I have 'APP_DIRS': True,